# Spring Tools Suite, JPA project and the JPA facet

Tags: spring-tool-suite

I am using a fresh install of STS 3.8.3 and I am unable to add the JPA facet to an EJB project:

[image]

If I try to create a JPA project, I cannot find that option:

[image]

I am certain these used to be available in STS.  What did I miss?

Answer (score 3):

We removed those extensions from the default distribution because users reported severe issues (search for JPA Event Handler on SO). In order to avoid this we decided to remove those tools from the distribution and added them to the extension install, so that you can get them back into STS quite easily.

However, we can revisit that decision in the future, if those tools don't cause those issues anymore.

Comment: As always Martin your answers are always informative. Can you describe how to get them back easily and where their removal were documented. Thanks

Comment: you can do to the dashboard, select the extension install, and there you find an entry for the Eclipse Data Tools.

Comment: i installed eclipse data tools (STS3.9) still don;t see the JPA facet. I need to create models from my tables

Comment: you are right, the data tools entry from the extension install doesn't include the full JPA tooling. You can go to "Install New Software", select the Eclipse Oxygen Update Site, and then search for the JPA tooling - and install it from there. This brings back the JPA tooling.

Comment: how to add it from eclipse extensions? I couldn't find them

Comment: Go to "Install New Software", select the main Eclipse p2 repository from the dropdown and wait until the content shows up, then select the features to install.

Answer (score 0):

Upon further investigation I discovered that the Eclipse Web Tools Platform at eclipse update site http://download.eclipse.org/webtools/repository/neon includes the following:
[image]

Why is this no longer configured in STS?  That is really too bad and not a good decision in my opinion.

Comment: Install new software is empty for me https://i.imgur.com/onyGQhf.png in STS 4

Answer (score 0):

Go to Help -> Install New Software -> in the work with drop down , choose one with "https://download.eclipse.org/releases/*".

In the result you will be able to see Database Development. 
Choose the database you wish to configure.

Comment: Install new software is empty for me https://i.imgur.com/onyGQhf.png in STS 4

Comment: you need to select the p2 repo from the dropdown.