# Spring boot jpa tool is not available in STS(Spring Tool Suite) for converting tables to entities

Tags: jpa, spring-boot-maven-plugin

Here i am working in Spring boot in Spring tool Suite.I want to convert an Oracle databse tables to JPA Class Entites. But i did not get any JPA tools in project_folder ->jpa tools. What i have to do can you please suggest a better solution. Thanks

Comment: how can i create a JPA project in STS tool it shows me spring starter project, maven project, java project etc. There is no option for JPA project

Comment: have you been able to solve this issue? I am too facing same issue right now

Answer (score 0):

Create a JPA project like so

```
File -> New -> JPA Project(Go to Others if JPA projects is not here)
```

After you have created your JPA project you can right click the project in the Project Explorer

```
Project Explorer -> Right-Click -> JPA Tools -> Generate Entities from Tables
```

Hope this helps.

### **Update 1**

If you are not getting options of creating a JPA project in your eclipse you might not be having the required tools for JPA support. Check [this](https://stackoverflow.com/a/42909260/3094731).

> You can go to "Install New Software", select the Eclipse Oxygen Update
>   Site, and then search for the JPA tooling - and install it from there.
>   This brings back the JPA tooling.

Comment: There is no JPA project. if i go to Others it gives me a searching Folder. There is no JPA

Comment: Go to Eclipse Marketplace and download the plugins for JPA support.

Comment: i tried but it does not give me jpa tool. i am not working in Eclipse which is upgraged to spring. i downloaded Spring Tool Suite

Comment: Please provide reasons for down-vote so that i can try to improve my answer.

Answer (score 0):

In order to Install New Software, go to Help\Install New Software..., select the Eclipse Oxygen Update Site: https://download.eclipse.org/releases/oxygen/, and then search for the JPA tooling.

Answer (score 0):

Eclipse Projects created as 'Spring Boot - Spring Starter Project' are not-faceted projects per default. Therefore there don't have the JPA-facet which offers the Wizzard to generate JPA entities from tables.

You need to add the `JPA-Project Facet` to your project.

```
Project > Properties > Project Facets > JPA
```

If your project is not configured to use project facets, you'll get a message asking if you want to convert it to a faceted project.

Answer (score 0):

Help -> Install New Software -> work with https://download/eclispe.org/releases/2019-03 -> filter 'JPA' ->
Uncheck 'Contact all update sites during install to find required software'

[image: 1]

Answer (score 0):

Try **installing** **Jboss** toll from marketplace, I had same issue and it is fixed now.