# How can I Install JPA in STS 3.9.4

Tags: java, eclipse, spring-boot, jpa

I Found no JPA in latest STS 3.9.4 .
Please suggest I cant even make new project as JPA project...

[image]

Comment: pls see if https://stackoverflow.com/questions/42869652/spring-tools-suite-jpa-project-and-the-jpa-facet answers your query. Looks like they removed it from recent sts versions.

Comment: Thanks @ShanuGupta

Comment: did that work? If yes pls post as answer.

Comment: No it didn't work for sts 3.9.4.. i started using eclipse oxygen. Thanks for your efforts.